# Is it possible to have fixed height table in rtf?

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, rtf

I'm trying to create rtf template. And in the output I need a table with fixed height it should cover page. But as record get added the table goes to next page.
Is it possible to have table with fixed height in rtf?. It shouldn't get affected by records getting added. I have tried attribute@incontext:xdofx:'fixed-height'.........code by oracle but it didn't work.

Please let me know if we have any workaround. Need it quickly